# how to pass audio input stream to skype?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, input, skype

Is it possible to pass arbitrary input stream to skype? I have a server where skype is installed(skype 4.3 version). Server has Ubuntu 14.10 distro, xorg and openbox packets installed for X Window management and no audio card, so i cannot use input stream like microphone. From Server side my purpose is to start playing audio file instead of using standard input during a skype call. Is it possible?